# What are “Pickups” in the Screen Time report?

Tags: ios, screen-time

In Screen Time introduces in iOS 12, part of the report is a graph for “Pickups”. What are these?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2018/9/17/17870126/ios-12-screen-time-app-limits-downtime-features-how-to-use) says that pickup counting is triggered “**when you’ve interacted with the device or on-screen content** in some way. If all you do is turn on the screen, that’s not enough to get tallied.”

If you’re looking for first-party confirmation, it seems like (for now) there’s nothing useful from Apple. [The](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208982) [only](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209084) [mentions](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/06/ios-12-introduces-new-features-to-reduce-interruptions-and-manage-screen-time/) of Screen Time pickups on their website describe it simply as “how many times a device was picked up,” or slight rewordings of that phrase. The WWDC 2018 [keynote](https://youtu.be/UThGcWBIMpU?t=2895) and Apple Support [video](https://youtu.be/BacXAmS6DLQ?t=29) on Screen time are similarly unhelpful.

(There were a dozen other tech blogs and websites that I also looked at, but all of them gave the same information as Apple, or less.)

Answer (score 6):

It’s the number of times that you have picked up the device to explicitly interact with it. The following interactions count:

- accelerometer
- screen unlock
- hey Siri

Comment: What counts as being “picked up”? Like, the accelerometer detected it vertically moved? That the display turned on? That I showed the home screen?

Answer (score 0):

It must be the time that the display is turned on because it is telling me that I got pickups in the middle of the night while I was asleep which was probably me getting notifications and the notifications turning my phone's display on.

Comment: Mine also shows pickups while I’m asleep. I thought I had a ghost using my phone. It must be the notifications coming through.